# Yup validation of website using url() very strict

Tags: reactjs, yup

I am trying to validate an input field as a website using

```
yup.string().url()
```

But it seems if the protocol is not sent it gives an error, when the website should be flexible to even accept for example `stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Instead of using default `url` validator you can use your own `regex`. Your code changes like:

```
website: Yup.string()
        .matches(
            /((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$/,
            'Enter correct url!'
        )
        .required('Please enter website'),
```

You can use your own rule for `regex` and validate url. You can read more about it [there](https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-options--message-string-excludeemptystring-bool--schema).

Play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/O47zyn/4

Comment: test this with `material-ui.com` here https://regex101.com/ it fails

Comment: `www.google` is marked as valid with this regex

Comment: Won't validate URLs like `https://localhost/blah`.
With URLs, the less validation the better.

Comment: There are some lacks here, like the one commented by Raul Madrigal (www.google is accepted).

Answer (score 18):

A lot of `urls` break on the verified answer. Something closer to `Yup.url()` but allowing the omission of http, www. and // would be:

```
const URL = /^((https?|ftp):\/\/)?(www.)?(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i

Yup.string().matches(URL, 'Enter a valid url')
```

Answer (score 18):

All the answers treat `www.mywebsite` as valid. Which should not be the case.

```
const re = /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/gm

Yup.string().matches(re,'URL is not valid')
```

matches:

- `vercel.com`
- `www.vercel.com`
- `uptime-monitor-fe.vercel.app`
- `https://uptime-monitor-fe.vercel.app/`

Comment: Tried to implement this and random test of:  fg.c passes regex validation

Comment: @Neo as it shuold...

Comment: Looks like it fails with trailing slash: `https://uptime-monitor-fe.vercel.app/`?

Answer (score 6):

Just completing @aturan23, you can add a `-` inside `[a-z0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9#]`, like this:

```
((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#-]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$
```

You can validate url like this:

- `material-ui.com`
- `https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui`
- `http://github.com/mui-org/material-ui`
- `github.com/mui-org/material-ui/core#teste`

Answer (score 6):

Adding some more validations to the @trash_dev's regex,

you could try https://regex101.com/r/V5Y7rn/1/

```
const regMatch = /^((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+(\/)?.([\w\?[a-zA-Z-_%\/@?]+)*([^\/\w\?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/;

Yup
 .string()
 .matches(regMatch, "Website should be a valid URL")
```

It also considered extra considerations for URL such as:

```
www.test-my-skills.gov.cz/0999asd-xzc88?0-_/sad%20123/@asdas
asdasd.com/asdasd/asdasd/asdasd/@asasd
https://www.somehow.com/@aasd
https://www.test.facebook.com/@sdas
http://www.computer.com.au/
```

Comment: Tried implementing this and random test of: faf.hi passes regex validation

Comment: faf.hi can be a possible domain name in future. Regex doesn't check the validity of the domain ofcourse. this passes that the test the extensions should be greater than one letter and it can be two letters to accommodate .in .us .co .me and probably who knows .hi If you wanna block certain extensions like .hi, you would need to come up with a improved regex.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
const isValidUrl = (url) => {
    try {
        new URL(url);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

const FormSchema = Yup.object({
    url: Yup.string().test('is-url-valid', 'URL is not valid', (value) => isValidUrl(value)),
});
```

https://dev.to/calvinpak/simple-url-validation-with-javascript-4oj5

Comment: Careful with this one

Validates:
`https://foo`
Fails:
google.com

Comment: This does not answer the question and causes the same problem when the protocol is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The other solution is simply use Yup [transform](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematransformcurrentvalue-any-originalvalue-any--any-schema).
You can do something like

```
Yup.string().url().transform((currentValue) => {
            const doesNotStartWithHttp =
              currentValue &&
              !(
                currentValue.startsWith('http://') ||
                currentValue.startsWith('https://')
              );

            if (doesNotStartWithHttp) {
              return `http://${currentValue}`;
            }
            return currentValue;
          })
```

This would automatically add `http` to your answer and would pass the validation.

Comment: this should be the real answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Im editing the @Animesh Singh's regex adding more validations.

First you need to think why are you validating this, will you store it somewhere? What are you trying to avoid? Depending on your answer you might add some custom validations to the regex.

I searched it and there is actually a limit on the length of url and the number of dots in the domain. A domain name can have hyphens too.

[https://news.gandi.net/en/2020/08/should-i-put-a-dash-in-my-domain-name/#:~:text=The%20hyphen%2C%20commonly%20known%20as,with%20no%20space%20between%20them](https://news.gandi.net/en/2020/08/should-i-put-a-dash-in-my-domain-name/#:%7E:text=The%20hyphen%2C%20commonly%20known%20as,with%20no%20space%20between%20them).

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) :

> The hierarchy of domains descends from the right to the left label in the name; each label to the left specifies a subdivision, or subdomain of the domain to the right. For example: the label example specifies a node example.com as a subdomain of the com domain, and www is a label to create [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), a subdomain of example.com. Each label may contain from 1 to 63 octets. The empty label is reserved for the root node and when fully qualified is expressed as the empty label terminated by a dot. The full domain name may not exceed a total length of 253 ASCII characters in its textual representation.[9] Thus, when using a single character per label, the limit is 127 levels: 127 characters plus 126 dots have a total length of 253. In practice, some domain registries may have shorter limits.

So I will set the length limit to 2048 characters and restraining the domain to have at most 126 single dots succeed by 63 characters. I don't see a way to check the 253 character domain limit without splitting the URL. I am not checking for hyphens here either.

So I am limiting how many `(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,63})` the url can have by switching `+` to `{1,5}`

```js
const regex = /^(?=.{4,2048}$)((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,63}){1,5}(\/)?.([\w\?[a-zA-Z-_%\/@?]+)*([^\/\w\?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/;

Yup
 .string()
 .matches(regMatch, "Website should be a valid URL")
```

In my use case I don't want the main domain, so I always require something after the slash by switching `(\/)?` to `(\/){1}`

```js
const regex = /^(?=.{4,2048}$)((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,63}){1,5}(\/){1}.([\w\?[a-zA-Z-_%\/@?]+)*([^\/\w\?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/;

Yup
 .string()
 .matches(regMatch, "Website should be a valid URL")
```

I ask everyone to test this regex, and let me know if there is any unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and most optimal is to re-use the regex from `Yup`.

You can create a new method or override the `url` method.

Here it is an example with Typescript overriding the `url` with an option to check the protocol as well.

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

type UrlOptions = {
  /** @default {false} */
  forceWithProtocol?: boolean;
};

/**
 * Regex got from Yup source-code, changing the protocol to be optional
 * @link {https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/src/string.ts#L20}
 */
const URL =
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape -- no warnings as it's copy/paste.
  /^(((https?):)?\/\/)?(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i;

// Override the original URL validation
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'url', function (message, options: UrlOptions = {}) {
  let validation = this.matches(URL, message);

  if (!options.forceWithProtocol) {
    return validation;
  }

  return validation.matches(/^(https?:\/\/)/, message);
});

declare module 'yup' {
  interface StringSchema {
    /** @override */
    url(message: string, options?: UrlOptions): this;
  }
}
```